# Variable initialization fails to compile with comma-operator

Tags: c++, variable-initialization

Why does the line indicated ( in main() ) in the following code not compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template< typename _T > struct Inventory : public std::map< _T, int >
{
    bool getat(int i, _T &t, int &n)
    {
        if ((i < 0) || (i >= (int)this->size())) return false;
        int c=0;
        typename std::map< _T, int >::iterator it = this->begin();

        while ((c < i) && (it != this->end())) { c++; it++; }
        t = (*it).first;
        n = (*it).second;
        return true;
    }
    Inventory &operator=(_T t) { (*this)[t]++; return *this; }
    Inventory &operator,(_T t) { return operator=(t); }
};

int main()
{
    int i=0, quantity;
    std::string item;

    //***Fails to compile:***
    //Inventory< std::string > inv = "a","b","c","a","c","d","e";  

    Inventory< std::string > inv;
    inv = "a","b","c","a","c","d","e";    //but this is fine
    inv = "e","f";

    while (i < (int)inv.size())
    {
        if (inv.getat(i, item, quantity)) 
                std::cout << i << ": " << item << " -> " << quantity << "\n";
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your compiler supports `#include <initializer_list>`you could play with `Inventory<std::string> inv { "a","b","c","a","c","d","e" }; `. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) for VS2012 (doesn't support).

Comment: @rubberboots: I'm using gcc; combining your suggestion with the `Collector`-idea from James Kanze's answer could be useful.

Comment: @slashmais - you don't need both. If the compilers you'll be using all support initializer lists, that's the way to go. If not, use the `Collector` idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called copy-initialization. In short, it uses the conversion constructor and then the copy constructor to construct `inv`, not `operator =` as you expect.

```
Inventory< std::string > inv = "a","b","c","a","c","d","e";
```

is invalid syntax. Something like `Inventory< std::string > inv = "a"` would first attempt to create a temporary `Inventory` from `"a","b","c","a","c","d","e"` and then use that temporary as argument to a copy constructor to construct `inv`. `operator =` is never called in this case.

Your second version works because

```
Inventory< std::string > inv;
```

calls the default constructor, and

```
inv = "a","b","c","a","c","d","e";
```

calls `operator =` on an already initialized object.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a constructor that can handle a randomly sized list like that? (I'm toying with comma-operator to get a feel for what it can and cannot do, and where it would be useful.)

Comment: Your explication is wrong.  In this case, the comma isn't an operator at all, but a separator: `Inventory<std::string> inv = "a", "b";` is the same as `Inventory<std::string> inv = "a"; Inventory<std::string> "b";`  And the compiler doesn't like it if the name of a variable is a string constant.

Comment: @JamesKanze While that's true, I don't see how the explanation is wrong.

Comment: @slashmais About the only thing overloading the comma operator can do is obfuscate.  An overloaded operator should behave in a way corresponding to the built-in operator.  Which means that you shouldn't overload operators which create sequence points.  (Overloading `&&` or `||` is also a bad idea.)  And in the case of comma, there's also the problem that sometimes it's an operator, and other times punctuation, and the overload is only applicable if it is an operator.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You say that the compiler would first attempt to create a temporary `Inventory` from `"a","b","c","a","c","d","e"`.  That's wrong: it will attempt to create a temporary from `"a"`, then to define a variable named `"b"` (which of course is illegal, since a string literal cannot be the name of a variable).

Comment: @JamesKanze aaa ok (I didn't compile the code), but yes, it's a declaration in the initialization case (I thought it would just use `"e"` to construct the temp). Will edit, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You're problem is that in one case, the comma is punctuation (and
operator overloading doesn't apply), and in the other, it is an 
operator.  The definition that doesn't work is basically the equivalent
of:

```
Inventory<std::string> inv = "a";
Inventory<std::string> "b";
Inventory<std::string> "c";
//  ...
```

Because of this, overloading `operator,` is always bad design; when the
comma is an operator, and when it isn't, is too subtle.

The usual way of doing something like this is to create a related class
to collect the arguments, and pass it into the constructor:

```
Inventory<std::string> inv = Collector().add("a").add("b")...;
```

You could also overload an operator and use it, instead of the function
`add`.  But I don't see a likely operator (`<<`, inspired by `ostream`?)
Or you could overload the constructor and the `operator()` of
`Collector`, and write:

```
Inventory<std::string> inv = Collector("a")("b")...;
```

You would then use the same syntax for assignment.  (You really don't
want something that works for assignment, and not for copy
construction.)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that messing with the comma is a bad idea, for instance something like `int i; i = 1,2,3; //result: i == 1` and `i = (1,2,3); //result: i == 3` can become troublesome. Your `Collector`-idea seems like a handy one, I'll play that as well.